# BackboneJS not creating the Wrapper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, backbone.js

I am creating a simple backbone template popup. Backbone is not creating the Wrapping `<div>` element that it was suppose to create. When the template is being generated there is no `<div class="theme-overlay">` is generated. Backbone dumps the html from template without any wrapper.

I have searched around but I haven't found any similar issue. I am very new with Backbone so I think I am missing something.

**NOTE:** I am working with WordPress environment that is why there is an `wp` global variable `wp.Backbone` is an internal adaptation of `Backbone` for avoiding conflict with PHP. Using `Backbone.View.extend()` instead of `wp.Backbone.View.extend()` gives me the same result.

### Find Code Below

```
window.wp = window.wp || {};

(function($){
    var importer = {};
    importer.data = _kallzuDemoSettings;
    _.extend( importer, { model: {}, view: {}, routes: {}, router: {}, template: wp.template });

    importer.View = wp.Backbone.View.extend({
        template: wp.template('demo'),
        el: '#theme-overlay',
        className: 'theme-overlay',
        events: {
            'click .close' : 'collapse'
        },
        render: function(demo_title){

            var data = _.find(importer.data.demos, function(item){
                return item.name == demo_title;
            });

            if( data == undefined ){
                alert( 'No data found!');
                return;
            }

            this.$el.html( this.template( data ) ); // insert into dom
        },
        collapse: function( event ) {

            var self = this;

            event = event || window.event;

            if ( $( event.target ).is( '.close' ) ) {

                // Add a temporary closing class while overlay fades out
                $( 'body' ).addClass( 'closing-overlay' );

                // With a quick fade out animation
                this.$el.fadeOut( 130, function() {
                    // Clicking outside the modal box closes the overlay
                    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'closing-overlay' );
                    // Handle event cleanup
                    self.closeOverlay();
                });
            }

        },

        closeOverlay: function() {
            $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'modal-open' );
            this.remove();
            this.unbind();
            this.trigger( 'importer:collapse' );
        },
    });

    window.installDemo = function( demo_title ){
        var view = new importer.View();
        view.render( demo_title );
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I don't think other part of the script like the template isn't necessary to show. But if you need them let me know in the comment.

Comment: ["`this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el). You can specify the `el` **xor** let Backbone build one using `tagName`, `className`, ... I always recommend that you let views create their own `el` rather than specifying `el: '...'`, then the caller can place the view's `el` somewhere on the page as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `el: '#theme-overlay'` and instead append the view to it after init.

```
window.installDemo = function( demo_title ){
    var view = new importer.View();
    view.$el.appendTo('#theme-overlay')
    view.render( demo_title );
}
```

This way, your wrapper div will be created and then appended to the div.

The DOM should end up looking like:

```
<div id="theme-overlay">
    <div class="theme-overlay"><!-- your rendered content --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have done similar but still wondering why my version of the code doesn't work. At least according to the doc it should. So, perhaps something has changed in latest version of the backboneJS. I am not frequent user so I can't confirm any of this.